# How do I Show Desktop like in Windows?

Tags: kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu (19.10 or 20.04 LTS), and when I press Window_key+D or hit the "show desktop" icon in the bottom-right corner, it hides my open windows and shows the desktop. However, when I open something else from my desktop, all the windows I had before come back up alongside the thing I just opened.

This is different from Windows, where if you show desktop, your open windows remain minimised even after you open something new.

Is there some way to get the Windows-like behaviour on KDE?

Comment: An answer from [this](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=140507) forum - "There is another widget that is essentially the same thing, only slightly different. It is called "minimize windows". I just tested it, and I believe it does the behavior that you are looking for (not sure why it is not the default)."
I'll make it a proper answer if that solves the issue. Thing is, I'm unsure if clicking it again would bring ONLY the minimized windows back to max. If not, I don't think it's the solution.

Comment: [This](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/plasma-minimize-all-or-show-desktop/85327/3) Might be also useful as there's a screenshot tutorial on how to set it as your desired hotkey. Again, let me know if that solves your issue, I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-July/000258.html) so you should *release-upgrade* asap if you're using 19.10, as Ubuntu 19.10 is now off-topic on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-reaches-end-of-life/

Comment: This is a KDE feature in question that's not exactly related to the Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thanks @RandomElephant, I've confirmed that the behaviour is the same on 20.04 LTS.

Comment: And @RandomElephant, right clicking on the show desktop icon (bottom right) and selecting "Minimize All Windows" does have the desired behaviour. Thanks again.

Comment: @RandomElephant, do please post an answer!